# How to send multiple asynchronous volley request?

Tags: android, listview, android-volley

I want to send 3 volley requests but when I want to do this, one or two requests won't be done and when I remove one request the two others work properly.

```
G.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mainListReq1);
G.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mainListReq2);
G.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(mainListReq3);

CustomRequest mainListReq1= new CustomRequest(Request.Method.POST,NEWS_TEN,null,
            new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                    String strResponse = response.toString();
                    Gson gson = new Gson();
                    NewsTenData postObj = gson.fromJson(strResponse, NewsTenData.class);
                    mtitleList = new ArrayList<>();

                    if (postObj.getCount() != 0) {
                        int sizeArray = postObj.getData().size();
                        for (int i = 0; i < sizeArray; i++) {
                            newsTtle = postObj.getData().get(i).getNew_title();
                            newsDes = postObj.getData().get(i).getNew_des();

                        }
```

...

```
                    } else {

                    }

                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {

        }
    }) {
        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("id", String.valueOf(id));
            return params;
        }
    };
```

Comment: use Interface callback.